# How to use Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am a newbie to meteor, so can anyone help me out , how to use `meteor` for mobile application development. I am not getting relevant tutorials for it. I am currently working on Ubuntu 14.0 LTS

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please read the rules about what kinds of questions are allowed here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: It would be much better if you could provide a minimal example of source code that you have tried already

Comment: @NathanWebb , would you suggest me, which methodology should i use to develop meteor apps, i mean whether i should use blaze, angular or react.

Comment: Start with blaze. But really, anything is better than nothing.

Comment: @NathanWebb i have the followed tutorials and made a simple to do list with angular but, i want to know the functions and keywords for every event associated. . I know Angular Js, but the way they incorporated it in meteor is little bit confusing to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just recently learnt meteor and I found these courses really helpful.

- https://www.coursera.org/learn/meteor-development
- https://www.coursera.org/learn/web-application-development

They show you how to get up and running and where to find all the info you're looking for.

Comment: Better to provide an explanation along with links as the links might turn obsolete in future

Answer (score 1):

Themeteorchef.com has excellent tutorials. Here's a great place to start:
https://themeteorchef.com/base/introduction

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15789582)

Comment: @ArtemPetrosian thanks I've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for providing the link.

Comment: @Sampad you're welcome, that site has a lot to explore. My favorite was when I wanted to learn react.js - it's called 'getting started with react.js'. Super clear since it explained react using a perspective I already understood - meteor. https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-react

Comment: @Sampad, another good tutorial that builds great group chat project to really understand the reactivity in Meteor - https://www.codementor.io/codeforgeek/getting-started-with-meteor-build-sample-app-du107r3o2

Comment: Thanks for the incredible help in this regards, the links you have provided is really helpful and highly appreciated.

Comment: Meteortips.com also incredible and easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

On the [Meteor Tutorials Page](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials) there is a tutorial on creating a [WhatsApp Clone in Meteor](http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp/meteor/bootstrapping) which is the mobile application development you are referring to.

What I found interesting is that while Meteor uses Blaze, Angular and React for rendering the web, the tutorials page seems to be directing mobile users to focus on Angular.

The web of course has many specific tutorials on what you are looking for:

- [Get Started Building Mobile Apps with Meteor](http://abstractcoder.com/2014/08/22/how-to-get-started-building-mobile-apps-with-meteor-js.html)
- [A Beginners Guide to Mobile Development with Meteor](https://www.sitepoint.com/beginners-guide-mobile-development-meteor/)
- [Quick Meteor Mobile App Tutorial](http://abstractcoder.com/2014/12/03/quick-meteor-mobile-app-tutorial.html)
- [W3Schools Angular JS Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/) because you need Angular